# conflicting ids in two different SVG files included in the same HTML document

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, svg

So I have a single .svg file with a few pre-made gradient effects like this:

```
<svg xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" height="1052.4" width="744.09" version="1.1" xmlns:cc="http://creativecommons.org/ns#" xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/" viewBox="0 0 670 680" style="width: 100%; height: 100%;">

<defs>
    <radialGradient id="grad1" cx="50%" cy="50%" r="50%" fx="50%" fy="50%">
        <stop offset="0%" style="stop-color: #a0a0a0;" />
        <stop offset="100%" style="stop-color: #a0a0a0;" />
    </radialGradient>
</defs>
 <g>
  <path id="path1" d="m124 263.35c6.4216-12.385 18.974-0.67157 0.72621z" fill="url(#grad1)">
  </path>
</g>
</svg>
```

This is a simplified version of my svg file. It represents a map in which each state is a path element. Each state also has a radialgradient tag associated with it. The problem I'm having is that I include this SVG file twice in my HTML document and I alter the radial gradient tags on the svg to alter the color of the state on each map separately.

The maps also have some interactivity in them, I use the following code to load the svg and to add events that bring a state to the front (so its stroke is visible) when the user hovers the mouse over the map:

```
$divSVG.load("map.svg", function() {
    $svg= $(this).find("svg");
    $svg.find("path").each(function() { 
        $(this).bind("mouseenter", function() {
                var $path= $(this);
            var $parent= $path.parent();
            //its necessary to detach and reattach the element so it comes to the front
            //of the image (there is no z-index in SVG)
            $path.detach();
            $parent.append($path);
            $path
                .css("stroke", "#FF0000")
                .css("stroke-width", "5px");
        });
        $(this).bind("mouseleave", function() {
            $(this)
                .css("stroke", "#FFFFFF")
                .css("stroke-width", "3px");
        });
    }
});
```

Basically I just remove the element and reattach it to its parent when the element is hovered.

The problem: when the element is reattached on the map that was added first in the document it starts using the radial gradient present on the second map. That means that when I hover the first map the states changes colors to the same colors they have on the second map.

I believe the cause of this is that since its the same file loaded twice the gradient ids are conflicting causing the reattached element to take its color from the last gradient tag found in the HTML document instead of the gradient tag present in its own SVG tag.

So here is my problem, how do I solve it? I don't want to create a new SVG file for each map with unique ids. Nor do I want to manipulate the ids by javascript. Any ideas?

Comment: How are you including the SVG file in your document?

Comment: @robertc I load it using a jQuery ajax request (.load method on one of the divs of my document). I edited my question to show it.

Comment: How about putting the SVG in an <iframe> or <object> tag so it's not part of the main page.

Comment: Then you're going to get problems with conflicting IDs unless you change the IDs when you load it.

Answer (score 9):

SVG injectors like Iconic [SVGInjector](https://github.com/iconic/SVGInjector) or the newer Iconfu [SVGInject](https://github.com/iconfu/svg-inject) handle this issue by making the IDs unique when inserting the SVG into the HTML document. The Iconic injector adds a running number to the ID (`grad1` becomes `grad1-1`), while the Iconfu injector adds a short random string (`grad1` becomes something like `grad1-4ew8ZeSw`).

Making IDs unique is not only necessary if two SVGs use the same ID, but also if the same SVG is used multiple times in an HTML document.

Comment: sad it works like this, fortunately there are now tools to help that weren't available back when the question was originally asked (2013). I don't remember how I solved this at the time, but I think I just manually changed the ids of the second map before adding it to the page

Comment: Just had a similar problem. Since I had CSS styles directed to the individual path id's of both SVGs, the solution was to change the id's of the filter definitions! It was necessary to change two things in one SVG:
1) the `id="path_xxx"` within <filter> to e.g. `id="path_xxx2"`
2) the `filter="url(#path_xxx)"`  within <g> to e.g. `filter="url(#path_xxx2)"`